# Upgrade from SBS2003 to full windows domain

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2003, upgrade

A company running SBS2003 wants to switch to the full windows domain (no longer SBS), including Exchange 2013.

How would they upgrade to a full domain, and how do they remove SBS?  Is there a set of steps that must be followed?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to this is: you can't.

Specifically, you can't **upgrade** an SBS site, you have to **replace** it with a new domain setup, then migrate or replicate the relevant data from the old SBS to the new Domain: Active Directory contents, Exchange data, etc.

There are various tools to help with the migration, but in general I've found that it is far simpler to recreate the AD structure and so on than to attempt to do a migration.  Especially since SBS has so many little quirks that you really, *really* don't want to follow you to a full-fledged domain.

When it comes time to do this, I would suggest that you resist the urge to do mailbox migration.  Have the users export their emails to PST and reload or attach the PST files when they start on the new Domain.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://www.sbsmigration.com/). Search for a kit that suits your needs. As an alternative, try reproducing your AD, Exchange etc. from scratch. Since in SBS you probaly have no more than 75 users/machines, it should be doable and is probably the cleaner way.